# Using Tcl info procs return value

Tags: error-handling, syntax-error, runtime-error, tcl

given that not_there isn't a proc I would expect

```
[info procs not_there] eq ""
```

to return 0, but I'm seeing

```
empty command name ""
```

could someone explain my conceptual error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement of yours:

```
[info procs not_there] eq ""
```

will first have `info procs not_there` evaluated by the Tcl interpreter.   Next the interpreter will evaluate the equivalent of this statement:

```
"" eq ""
```

...where the first word `""` is not a valid command.

In the Tcl statements, the first word must always be a command.  command arg arg arg...

What you're missing is using the `expr` command at the beginning

```
expr {"" eq ""}                       --> 1
expr {[info procs not_there] eq ""}   --> 1
```

By the way, the `expr` is implied in the conditional argument of the `if` statement:

```
if {[info procs not_there] eq ""} {
     puts "This is not a proc"
}
```

Comment: and, bizarrely imo, the opening brace of the body has to be on the same line as the closing brace of the conditional.

Comment: That's just Tcl syntx.   Each line of code is considered a complete command, unless there is an unclosed curly brace or a line continuation backslash.   If so, then the next line will be concatenated to the command.    It does not just keep adding characters across newlines until it gets to a semicolon.